# Can we edit Spring validation annotation without changing the source code?

Tags: regex, spring, validation, annotations

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+"
    private String number;

}
```

Have requirement to support negative number at production site. Is there a way we can change regex value or disabling validation without changing the source class? any configuration to add in xml?

I know we can edit regex but looking for option without editing source file.

Comment: Try `@Pattern(regexp="^-?\\d+$",message="field must contain positive or negative numbers only")`

Comment: I had to look up "Spring". It could refer to a season or a resilient device, typically a helical metal coil, but I expect you are referring to a Java framework, in which case you may wish to add a "java" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses regex validation, so you can simply tweak the regex pattern like this:

```
public class Foo {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "-?[0-9]+")
    private String number;
}
```

However, if you mean about parameterizing the pattern, then you can use a property like this:

```
public class Foo {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "${regex.pattern}")
    private String number;
}
```

And add in `application.properties` the property

```
regex.pattern=-?[0-9]+
```

Comment: Thank you. But we don't have access to change the file as it is deployed already. Is there way we can change/disable validation

Comment: @Pavan; I guess you can access the `application.properties`. Isn't it?Without it I think there will be problems in achieving your target.

Comment: we can access to application.properties but code doesn't have this placeholder ${regex.pattern}

Comment: @Pavan if you don't have access to the source code, you will have to download the deployed binary, decompile, modify and redeploy it. You can't achieve what you want without modifying either the source code or the binaries

Comment: The value won't work as it needs to be a static value nor does the validation framework knows where the get the value from. So the replacing won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum not sure what you mean, I'm already using this code

Comment: I highly doubt that it does work or that it is in a validation based annotation.